# Trying to animate lines of a grid onto the screen in a WPF app and detect how many can fit on the screen at a time

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a food menu that displays on a TV screen in a restaurant. There will be no interaction of the menu itmes, so I need to automatically display the items and rotate through them when all the items do not fit on the screen at one time.

I have all of the components of the project built, even the administration of what the menu items are and which day to display them. Now, I need to finish the display of the items for the TV screen(s).

I am new to WPF, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this:

1. Menu items are listed with the name of the item along with calories, protein, fat, and cholesterol. Because of this, they need to be displayed in a grid.
2. There is no user interaction with the menu, so I need to make sure that I can properly break up the list of items into "pages" that animate on and off the screen after displaying for several seconds. The way I was thinking of doing this was to add each item on the view and evaluate how much space is available beneath it. If the space is less than a certain height, the rest of the menu items are queued for display on the next "page". It would be nice to have each line item rapidly slide in from the left, having all of them appear on the screen within 1-2 seconds.
3. What is the best control to display them with? An ItemsControl, perhaps?

Any great ideas you guys have that can point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Update: Here's a very rough mockup of what I'm talking about: [image]

Comment: the behaviour you describe looks somehow like a WrapPanel.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: HighCore, I've just added a rough mockup. Vincent, I'm not sure the WrapPanel would work for me since these need to be individual line items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably get away with using a Grid or StackPanel and animate the margin value of your elements (use negative margins to slide items in). You need to ensure that the parent element has ClipToBounds set to false so that items can be drawn outside of its bounds.

To measure an element's height, just use the Measure method on the row element to figure out how much space it needs vertically. Based on that, you can determine how many elements you can fit in one page.

Comment: I think I understand. If I use a Grid, for instance, is it possible to individually animate the margin values of each row? I would like to slide the first row in, and once that starts sliding, slide in the 2nd row, and when that one starts sliding, slide in the 3rd row...

In this case, would the Grid be the parent that I need ensure the ClipToBounds is set to false? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you would set ClipToBounds to false on the Grid itself. Using a Grid is probably complicated though because each item can have a Row and Column associated with it. If you use a vertical StackPanel, and then as each row, add a horizontal StackPanel, things will probably be easier. In that case, you can add each "row"'s StackPanel to the vertical StackPanel and then animate the margin property from a large negative value to 0.

Comment: If all else fails, you can retreat to Canvas. I'd try to stay away from it though as much as possible.

Comment: I've created the vertical StackPanel with horizontal StackPanels within for the actual rows. The only problem is, I'm having a hard time getting the columns to line up, since it's not in a grid. The first column needs to be variable length (*), where as the last 4 are fixed. This is so it can scale to the end user's screen resolution/window size. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: You can use a Grid with a single row and your desired columns in lieu of the inner horizontal StackPanels. That way you should be able to get the desired column behavior you want. :) Make sure that the inner Grid's width is set to the same amount (you probably want them to expand to all the available width)

Comment: This answer put me on the right path. I ended up using a DataGrid, putting it in a Border and set up a StoryBoard transition animation for the Border that fades in and slides in from the left each time the content of the DataGrid is changed. This happens every 10 seconds and looks very nice! Thank you for putting me on the right track, Ameen!

Answer (score 0):

There's too much work to build everything, however the following should lead you to your goal :

Inherit from Listview add create a 'PartialListView' , with added dependencies properties StartIndex and ItemHeight. It should build a listview of the right height showing items from StartIndex to StartIndex+ItemHeight. (scroller not shown. Use FindDescendant (of type scrollviewer) to find the scrollViewer after listView is loaded, and set its VerticalOffset)

Create a UserControl with two dependency properties :
  1) bind to an ObservableCollection of MenuItems (Item, Calories, ...)
  2) an ItemHeight (integer property).

Then on each collection change you modify IndexList, an Observable collection of numbers {1, 6, 11 }, which are the first indexes of each menu.

The control code will look like :

```
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding IndexList, ElementName = mycontrolname}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScroller"  ... set to horizontal only, not
                                 showing any bar > 
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ScrollViewer> 
                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <app:PartialListView   StartIndex="{Binding }"  
                                 IndexCount  = "{Binding IndexCount, ElementName = mycontrolname}"
                                 ItemsSource = "{Binding MenuItems , ElementName = mycontrolname}"
                   />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

switching 'screen' will be done by changing the HorizontalOffset of the PageScroller ScrollViewer.